# Getting the last number in a string (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, regex

`var str = "7-Dec-1985"`
`var str = "12-Jan-1703"`
`var str = "18-Feb-1999"`

How would I got about pulling just the year out of the string? I have tried a number of different RegExp but none seem to be working.

I would have expected `re = new RegExp(/(\d+)\D*\z/);` To have worked but sadly it did not.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated

Comment: Note that `re = new RegExp(/(\d+)\D*\z/);` is actually creating two regex objects, the first being `/(\d+)\D*\z/` which is then passed to the `RegExp` contstructor. Normally you would use `new RegExp` only if you have the need construct the pattern dynamically which you would then pass as a string to the constructor. In all other cases `re = /(\d+)\D*\z/;` is perfectly ok.

Comment: There's no reason you need a regular expression here. RegExp is, in general, expensive and should be used with care.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since all of your `str`(s) use `-` as a separator, this will work for you:

```
var str = "7-Dec-1985",
    arr = str.split('-'),
    year = arr[2];

console.log(year);
```

Comment: Never use a regex when you can use a split.

Comment: Thanks very much, this works perfectly. Turns out though that there is a bit more information after the year. "7-Dec-1985 12:00 AM" Am I able to easily remove the time from the string?

Comment: "7-Dec-1985 12:00 AM".split(' ')[0].split('-')[2]

Comment: Simply parsing the result into an int solved this issue. Cheers again!

Answer (score 19):

this should do it

```
var year = str.match(/\d+$/)[0];
```

Comment: FYI str.match returns null if nothing found

Answer (score 3):

I'd try: `/.*(\d{4})$/`

Test your regex's here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html