# Why does't regex match all numbers instead of numbers just at the end of the string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I was just looking for a regex that would watch the last numerical (\d or [0-9]) in a given string , strings like:

```
var str = "7-Dec-1985"
var str = "#scrollto-section-4"
```

Of-course I found an answer in the following thread on SO **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408563/getting-the-last-number-in-a-string-javascript)**

I am using a regex like the following:

```
str.match(/\d+$/)
```

Works fine, no issues, now I used the following tool to analysis the regex **[HERE](https://regex101.com/)**,

```
\d+ //matches  greedy 0 to as many 
$ - specifies that the search should start at the end of the string
```

But why does that above regex in the below example:

```
var str = "7-Dec-1985"
```

Match only `1985` why not `71985` ?

Comment: Because there are other characters between `7` and `1` that are not matched by `\d`

Comment: @SebastianProske yes i was guessing that was the answer , Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `$` means "end of input" (or "end of line or end of input" if you specify the `m` flag), and `\d+` means a *contiguous* series of digits (not digits mixed with other things). So `\d+$` means "a contiguous series of digits right before the end."

If you want to match anywhere, remove the `$`. Additionally, if you want to match more than once, you'll need a `g` ("global") flag on it.

Examples -- your original:

```js
var str = "7-Dec-1985";
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(str.match(/\d+$/));
```

Without the `$`, but no `g`:

```js
var str = "7-Dec-1985";
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(str.match(/\d+/));
```

Without the `$` and with `g`:

```js
var str = "7-Dec-1985";
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(str.match(/\d+/g));
```

Comment: and to get the numbers all munged together, you could do `str.match(/\d+/g).join('')`

Comment: @TJ Thank you sir ! Fantastic answer ! :)

Comment: Great answer ... But look, You have 400k rep .. So please let us to answer this kind of questions *(easy)* and you can answer hard questions `;-)`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but `$` doesn't means start search at end of string.

Your regex `\d+$` means **match the number at end of string**.

To match any number use `\d+` [like this](https://regex101.com/r/xS0bY8/1).

Answer (score 2):

Because there is `-Dec-` between `7` and `1985` which isn't digit. Also `$` means end of line. So Your pattern just matches that number which is end of string *(continuously)*.